# GWT TextBox - Notification of value changes during editing

Tags: java, gwt

I have a `TextBox` on a `Panel` and I want to be notified when the value of the 'TextBox' changes.

I have tried the following event handlers:

- `ChangeHandler`
- `ValueChangeHandler`
- `KeyPresshandler`

My problem is that the `ValueChangeHandler` and `ChangeHandler` only fire when the focus leaves the controls. The `KeyPressHandler` fires correctly, but before the `TextBox` itself has seen the event, which means that a call to `getText()` from my event handler sees a stale value.

Is there an event that would work exactly like `KeyPressHandler` but be fired **after** the `TextBox` has seen the event?

EDIT: this behaviour is seen in Chrome and IE8 on Windows XP

Comment: Same behavior seen on Linux/Firefox 3.6.8.

Comment: Related [Instant value change handler on a GWT TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184648/instant-value-change-handler-on-a-gwt-textbox)

Comment: I think there is already an solution for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201132/gwt-input-event-on-textbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [KeyUpHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpHandler.html).

Comment: I have a "friend" who searched for it for hours, too ;)

Answer (score 2):

A very robust (though not very elegant) solution which catches ALL changes including copy/pasty via mouse or text suggestions inserted via a virtual keyboard (e. g. such as the ios 8 keyboard) is to start a timer on focus and to check the value of the textbox in an appropriate time interval. 
The timer is stopped on blur (don't forget to do a final check on blur).

I am not aware of any "handler-based" solution to catch all textbox changes.