# Instant value change handler on a GWT textbox

Tags: events, gwt, textbox

I would like to update a text field instantly when typing in a GWT TextBox. My problem is that ValueChangeEvent and ChangeEvent handlers only fire when the TextBox loses focus. I thought about using the KeyPressEvent but then nothing would happen when performing a copy paste with the mouse.

What's the simplest way to do that ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could catch the `ONPASTE` event and manually fire a `ValueChangeEvent`. Something like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Label text = new Label();
    final ExtendedTextBox box = new ExtendedTextBox();
    box.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
            text.setText(event.getValue());
        }

    });
    box.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            text.setText(box.getText());
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(box);
    RootPanel.get().add(text);
}

private class ExtendedTextBox extends TextBox {

    public ExtendedTextBox() {
        super();
        sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
            case Event.ONPASTE:
                Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

                    @Override
                    public void execute() {
                        ValueChangeEvent.fire(ExtendedTextBox.this, getText());
                    }

                });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on firefox 3.6.1.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me.  One thing for others to note is that the deferred command is required because the TextBox does not yet contain the text of interest when the paste event is handled.  If you are trying to filter the contents of the text box (in my case, for valid characters), note that a user will momentarily see the pasted text.  Anyone know any ways around this? From what I've read, FF does not allow clipboard inspection, but both IE and Webkit do?

Comment: What you could do is to hide the content of the `TextBox` until validation is done. It's really a hack but `color: transparent` would do the trick...

Comment: @z00bs Is this possible to do without extending TextArea and using UiBinder?

Comment: I doubt it since you somehow need to extend the behavior in `onBrowserEvent()`.

Comment: Great answer, but in recent versions of GWT, DeferredCommand has been deprecated in favour of Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(...)

Comment: Instead of extending TextBox you could simply use JSNI like here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4018317/193016

Answer (score 4):

As a general solution, what works for me (thx to gal-bracha comment):

Generally, GWT does not have classes to handle input event (described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)
 and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)). So we need to implement it by ourselves:

Handler class:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler;

public interface InputHandler extends EventHandler {

  void onInput(InputEvent event);

}
```

Event class:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent;

public class InputEvent extends DomEvent<InputHandler> {

    private static final Type<InputHandler> TYPE = new Type<InputHandler>("input", new InputEvent());

    public static Type<InputHandler> getType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    protected InputEvent() {
    }

    @Override
    public final Type<InputHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(InputHandler handler) {
        handler.onInput(this);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
box.addDomHandler(new InputHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onInput(InputEvent event) {
        text.setText(box.getText());
    }
},InputEvent.getType());
```

It works on every TextBox value change including pasting using context menu. It does not react on arrows, ctrl, shift etc...

Comment: Missing "(" after new Type<InputHandler>.

Comment: I get this error during creation: exception 2 (String) : Trying to sink unknown event type input

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has been a major issue for me in the past. The keyupHandler wont work because the copy paste requires a second key press on the paste option which does not fire the event. the best i have been able to do is use the old changelistener not ideal but it does work.

Comment: Better to use the input event, But I'm not sure how to access it from gwt. It handles both paste, and keyboard, as it raises when the value actually changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use `Elements` than `Widgets` so this my way to handler.

```
    Element input = Document.get().getElementById("my-input");
    DOM.sinkBitlessEvent(input, "input");
    DOM.setEventListener(input, event -> GWT.log("Event!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use combination of both KeyUpHandler and a ChangeHandler on the TextBox? 
Should take care of immediate feedback on each keystroke as well as copy paste case as well.

Comment: As I said the ChangeHandler only fires once the TextBox loses focus but I would like to update my field instantly (while the user is typing).

Comment: Hmmm... Did you figure out a way? Please shares the solution when you do :) Thanks

Comment: The behaviour change on lose of focus was accepted after all for the app I was working on. So I never did find a solution and left it aside for the moment. But will update the question if ever I find one.

Comment: Best thing is to use the input event, But I'm not sure how to access it from gwt.
It handles both paste, and keyboard, as it raises when the value actually changes.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input

Answer (score 0):

```
Just saw this question. Because I was facing the similar problem.
```

Did some hack and it worked for me. 
You can use KeyUpHandler but use it with additional if block that checks
 for length of textbox. If length of text box is > 0,  do your thing.
    Ex:

```
textBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent keyUpEvent) {
    if (textBox.getText().length() > 0) {
    //do your stuff`enter code here`

    }
    }
```

Comment: This does not account for dragging values into the box, also triggers on left/right keyrelease, ctrl keyrelease

Comment: true, this will be applicable for typing which includes text. I guess that will serve purpose for this question. Its just a hack ;)