# GWT pasting event

Tags: gwt, copy-paste

I want to handle events when user pastes some text in `TextBox`. Which event is fired in this situation? I tried `ValueChange` and `Change` handlers, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/5d9a6fbe9e2bacf2) might help you. Describes a workaround to hook to the onpaste event. 
In short:

- subclass `TextBox`
- sink the onpaste event in the constructor

  ```
  sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);
  ```
- override `onBrowserEvent(Event event)`

  ```
  public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
      super.onBrowserEvent(event);
      switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
          case Event.ONPASTE: {
              // do something here
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Link is dead. I assume it was meant to be http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/5d9a6fbe9e2bacf2

Comment: I know this is old now. I'm commenting this because I'm hitting a situation, not sirous, but worth some awareness. My box is sopposed to be numeric, so I'm adding onclick, onblur and the sink for onpaste. Thing is, with on paste, the click and blur events are not fired from the handlers I added, rather they are fired on the onBrowser event. Why is this?

Comment: I meant KeyUp, not click event. ;)

Comment: Hi z00bs, can you please give the overall code, how it fits together. I mean, where do we attach the `onBrowser` and `sinkEvent` methods?

Comment: `sinkEvent` is called in the constructor of the widget (as I wrote) and the `onBrowserEvent()` method you don't need to 'attach' just overwrite it to handle the newly sunk event. It's being called by GWT if any of the sunk events is triggered.

Answer (score 7):

GWT does not yet have support for cut, copy & paste: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4030

Edited: 
Another option is to use JSNI. For example add this to your GWT class:

```
public native void addCutHandler(Element element)
    /*-{
        var temp = this;  // hack to hold on to 'this' reference
        element.oncut = function(e) {
            temp.@org.package.YourClass::handleCut()();
        }
    }-*/;

public void handleCut() {
    Window.alert("Cut!");
}
```

Comment: I combined this answer with the following to get textbox content after a paste: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895059/how-to-alert-after-paste-event-in-javascript. I also wanted to add that I prefer this method because it seems simpler to me than extending a class.

Answer (score 1):

```
**(Write In the Constructor)**

sinkEvents( Event.ONPASTE );   

**(After that write below code)**

public void onBrowserEvent( Event event )
{
    super.onBrowserEvent( event );
    switch ( event.getTypeInt() )
    {
        case Event.ONPASTE :
        {
             event.stopPropagation();
             event.preventDefault();
             break;
        }
    }
}
```