# JavaScript setTimeout 0 blocking page rendering?

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986295/is-innerhtml-asynchronous) StackOverflow question

> Changing the DOM is synchronous. Rendering the DOM actually happens after the JavaScript stack has cleared.

and according to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/) google doc the screen fresh rate 60fps is equivalent to roughly refreshing every 16ms, I write this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                document.querySelector('#do').onclick = function() {
                    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = 'calculating...';
                    // setTimeout(long, 0); // will block
                    setTimeout(long, 1); // will not block
                };

                function long(){
                  let result = 0
                  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                      for (let k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
                        result += i + j + k;
                      }
                    } 
                  }
                  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = 'calculation done';
                  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result.toString();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id='do'> Do long calc!</button>
        <div id='status'></div>
        <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

with jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u96tvbf1/)

I played around with the code and found that blocking happens with time delay under 12ms, and happens more often with lesser delay.

I have two different ways of comprehension:

1. In this case only `setTimeout` with time delay over 16ms should not block, time delay of 0 and 1 are way less than 16ms so both of them should block;
2. Right after `setTimeout` call and `long` pushed to message queue (with optional delay), now the call stack is empty so in both cases `setTimeout` should not block and 'calculating...' always be rendered.

What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possibly to do with your [browser throttling the delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified).

It reads as though most browsers disregard a value of 0, might be worth looking at the `DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE` for your browser.

Comment: Thanks reddington that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on the information provided ad MDN. Without the link your answer does not provide enough information. At least quote the relevant information.