# Why is while loop running before html DOM assignment in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Below, why does while loop run before document.body.style.backgroundColor assignment?

```js
console.log("loadded");

const btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  const start = Date.now();
  const delaySeconds = 10;
  while (Date.now() < start + delaySeconds * 1000) {}
});
```

```html
<button id="button">test</button>
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986295/is-innerhtml-asynchronous/42986563#42986563