# How to get updated DOM element in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to better understand the relationship between how JavaScript updates DOM object.
Here is my html file `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">old</div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

and here is my JavaScript file `script.js`,

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
console.log(container, container.innerHTML);
container.innerHTML = "new";
console.log(container, container.innerHTML);
```

The console logs the same `<div>` tag but with different `innerHTML` which is quiet unexpected:

```
<div id="container">new</div> 'old'
<div id="container">new</div> 'new'
```

Therefore my 1st question is, what makes it possible for the console to print the same `div` elements but different `innerHTML`?

---

Secondly I made a small change to my script with `setTimeout`,

```
let timeout = 30;
setTimeout(() => {
  container.innerHTML = "new";
  console.log(container, container.innerHTML);
}, timeout);
```

Though `container.innerHTML` are always printed with different value, as expected, I found out that if the timeout value is above 35. The `div` tag is almost certainly printed differently with,

```
<div id="container">old</div> 'old'
<div id="container">new</div> 'new'
```

Then something I don't understand happens. When `timeout` is set below 10, it is almost certain that `div` tag are printed as,

```
<div id="container">new</div> 'old'
<div id="container">new</div> 'new'
```

When `timeout` is set somewhere between 10 and 30ish, the result toggles, meaning sometimes

```
<div id="container">new</div> 'old'
<div id="container">new</div> 'new'
```

and sometimes

```
<div id="container">old</div> 'old'
<div id="container">new</div> 'new'
```

Therefore my second question is, what causes this difference?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: [The console is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, I can respond to both questions with this:

Note that the `innerHTML` property is *synchronous*, meaning that the next line should not execute until that process finishes. However, the actual DOM must render again, and this happens separately (or *asynchronously*). The visual rendering in the DOM is not happening until after your stack of functions in JavaScript completes. Thus, your `console.log()` commands are retrieving information before the DOM has rendered with new HTML code.

You are seeing this with what you've shown in your second question. When you use a `setTimeout()` between 10 and 30ms, *sometimes* the DOM rendered again quick enough for your `console.log()` to now execute on the updated `innerHTML`. Of course, program and function execution across programming never completes at the exact same times for all kinds of reasons.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986295/is-innerhtml-asynchronous) thread may help you in understanding.

Comment: innerHTML also triggers a page reflow, so it may not be finished with the reflow with 1/100 of a second.  innerHTML also does some extra work of parsing the html, if any.  Did you try this with textContent and get the same results?

Comment: @CharlesOwen Hi, just did the test. Substituting `container.innerHTML` with `container.textContent` records similar behavior.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I still can't get my head around. Per "...console.log() commands are retrieving information before the DOM has rendered with new HTML code", shouldn't the second console.log print the "old <div>" element which is `<div id="container">old</div> 'old'` instead of `<div id="container">new</div> 'old'`?