# GXT3 NumberField disable paste feature

Tags: java, gxt

I'm using com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.NumberField and I want disable the paste feature.

For example, currently, I can paste (using Ctrl+V or with contextual menu of mouse) the text "A", and after I get a parse error, but I want not get the parse error, disallowing the paste feature.

This is my code, but I not have idea how disable the paste feature.

```
    private NumberField<Integer> createNumberField() {
    NumberField<Integer> numberField = new NumberField<Integer>(
            new IntegerPropertyEditor());
    numberField.setAllowDecimals(false);
    numberField.setAllowNegative(false);
    numberField.setAllowBlank(true);
    numberField.setEmptyText("0");
    numberField.setAutoValidate(false);
    numberField.setClearValueOnParseError(false);
    numberField.setValidateOnBlur(true);


    numberField.addParseErrorHandler(new ParseErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onParseError(ParseErrorEvent event) {
            Info.display("Parse Error", event.getErrorValue()
                    + " could not be parsed as a number");
        }
    });

    return numberField;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy, cut, paste feater isn't native in GWT/GXT.
You can see in this stackoverflow pages somme reponses : [GWT pasting event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018118/gwt-pasting-event)