# How can I get the onChangeEvent _sooner_?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, dom-events

I'm using GWT to monitor changes to a TextArea.  When the user types, I catch `KeyPressEvents` and update my logic accordingly.

However, when the user uses the mouse to change the value of the TextArea (e.g. cut & paste or drag) I do not get `KeyPressEvents` (of course).  I still want to update immediately.  I tried `ChangeEvents`, but it seems that they are only fired much later, when the TextArea loses focus.

I could listen for all `ClickEvents`, but is there a more logical mechanism that will alert my code right after the text in a textarea changes for any reason?

Comment: I guess there is not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184648/instant-value-change-handler-on-a-gwt-textbox/4085371#4085371 is what I did when I came across the need to get instant feedback. Maybe helpful in your case as well.

Comment: Have you tried "cut" and "paste" listeners?

Comment: You want to get events when the mouse is clicked, but you don't want to listen for ClickEvents?  I don't get it.

Comment: Not all possible `ClickEvents` on the `TextArea` cause the content to change so @Riley is not really interested in all of them since only content changes matter. Listening to all `ClickEvents` and checking for changes would be a workaround but is no ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks @z00bs, yours is the best solution I've found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like catching the paste & cut events directly is the best way - there's no "changed-at-all" event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use setTimeout:

```
var ta = document.getElementById("yourTextarea");
var value = ta.value;

function check() {
    if ( ta.value !== value ) {
        // value has changed
        value = ta.value;
    }
    setTimeout(check, 100);
}

check();
```